# Drawline with same pen width, but the line widths are different in result

Tags: c#, line, draw

I draw lines with the same pen, but the line widths are different in result. Why?

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(400, 400);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;
g.Clear(Color.White);
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1.2f);

for (int i = 20; i < 200; i = i + 20)
{
    g.DrawLine(pen, 10, i, 190, i);
}

g.Dispose();
b.Save("d:/temp/test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
b.Dispose()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN for GraphicsUnit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit(v=vs.110).aspx)

It's because you're working with Points and not Pixels and the variation in the width of the lines is the result of a rounding errors in the placement of the line and the width of the line in relation to how it gets rendered in pixels in the final product.

If you don't care about printing the image, it might be best to stick with Pixels.

Edit: If you want to continue using points, space things relative to your pen width:

```
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(400, 400);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

        g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Point;
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1.2f);

        for (float i = 20f * pen.Width; i < 200f * pen.Width; i = i + 20f * pen.Width)
        {
            g.DrawLine(pen, 10f, i, 190f, i);
        }

        g.Dispose();
        b.Save("c:/temp/test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        b.Dispose();
```

Comment: See my edit, which seemed to get the result you might have been looking for. If your pen width is what must stay constant, space and place things relative to that value.